# SQLite Database Retrieve IOS

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I have SQLite database with four columns

Example :

```
id     Name      Email            Mobile
-------------------------------------------
1     Vishal     V@gmail.com      5654485
2     Raval      R@gmail.com      5544555
3     VVV                         55555
4     RRRR                             
5     TTTT       T@gmail          5555
```

I want a particular column value in particular array.

For example :

- in NameArray I want all the values that are stored in Name column of database
- in EmailArray I want all the values that are stored in Email column of database

Comment: No you don't, you want each row in it's own, custom, model class.

Comment: By the way, while we're suggesting you use separate arrays, I'd also suggest that you might want to adopt [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa: Naming Properties and Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE). So, instead of `NameArray` and `EmailArray`, you might use `nameArray` and `emailArray` or just `names` and `emails`. Obviously, you don't have these separate arrays at all, but as a general observation, you might want to adopt these naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you simply instantiate your array(s), iterate through the SQLite results, adding object(s) to your array(s) as you go along.

The long answer:

1. I agree with trojanfoe that you should *not* be maintaining separate arrays for the four columns of your table. You should have a single class, e.g. `Contact`, that holds all four column values, and then build an array of those. So, that class might look like:

   ```
   @interface Contact : NSObject

   @property (nonatomic) long long contactId;
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email;
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *mobile;

   @end

   @implementation Contact

   // nothing required here

   @end
   ```
2. You say you are using SQLite. I would suggest that you consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). This is a thin wrapper around the [SQLite C-language API](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html) and greatly simplifies your interaction with SQLite databases. My example below will use this FMDB library.
3. So, as suggested in the "short answer", you just have to iterate through your SQL results, adding items to an array:

   ```
   FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
   BOOL success = [database open];
   NSAssert(success, @"database open failed");

   FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"select id, name, email, mobile from test"];
   NSAssert(rs, @"select failed: %@", [database lastErrorMessage]);

   NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

   while ([rs next])
   {
       Contact *contact = [[Contact alloc] init];
       contact.contactId = [rs longLongIntForColumn:@"id"];

       id name = rs[@"name"];
       if (name != [NSNull null])       // if the column can be NULL, you might want to check for that condition
           contact.name = name;

       id email = rs[@"email"];
       if (email != [NSNull null])
           contact.email = email;

       id mobile = rs[@"mobile"];
       if (mobile != [NSNull null])
           contact.mobile = mobile;

       [contacts addObject:contact];
   }

   [rs close];
   ```
4. Now, you can access information from that `contacts` array like so:

   ```
   Contact *contact = contacts[2];
   NSString *email = contact.email;
   ```

   That first line retrieves a reference to the third contact. The next line retrieves the email address from that contact. Hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Clearly, if you're determined to use the SQLite C-language interface (e.g. calls to `sqlite3_open`, `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, etc.), you can, but it requires a lot more work (especially when you get into using parameters to your SQL statements). I strongly recommend using FMDB.

And likewise, if you want to have separate arrays for the four columns of your table, you can do that, but using a class like the aforementioned `Contact` class is far more elegant and results in more logical code.

Comment: Thank You So much Mr.Rob For Reply....bt i was not use FMDB before so that's why its little Difficult for me...

Comment: @Saytovishal If you need to see `sqlite3_xxx` calls rendition, let me know, but, believe me, you'll thank yourself if you make the shift to FMDB sooner rather than later.

Comment: Oh..k Mr.ROB...i Will Try it Now..and Thank You so much Again..

Comment: Mr.Rob as i Define in the table the Name Column Contain 5 Values and Email Column Contain Only 3 Values..so it's Working Propertly For My Problem that i Listed Upper..?

Comment: @Saytovishal Yes. The above should work fine in that scenario (though be aware that if a column is NULL, this will return `[NSNull null]`).

Comment: @Mr.Rob    Oh..k Mr.Rob Thank You so Much...i currently Working on Method as u Suggest Me.

Comment: @Saytovishal If you'd rather not store `[NSNull null]` values, you can add a check for that like in my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute fetch request first like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:yourTable inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Refer to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html

Then you need to do the following:

```
NSArray *names = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.Name"];
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: What's CoreData got to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of things to do:

1. put the database within the app
2. import the library sqlite3
3. create two files as a subclass of NSObject (call database)
4. import in database.h

now the code to be written in database.h:

> @interface database : NSObject {
>
> ```
> NSString *databaseName;   
> NSString *databasePath;
>
>  }
>  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *databaseName; 
>  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *databasePath;
>
> -(void)startDB;
> -(void)checkAndCreateDatabase;
> ```

and now .m:

```
@implementation database : NSObject
@synthesize databasePath, databaseName;

-(void)startDB {

   // Setup some globals
   databaseName = @"yourdb.sqlite";

  // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
  NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
  databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

  // Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
   [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

}


 -(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
 // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
 BOOL success;

 // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
 // of the database and to copy it over if required
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
 success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

 // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
 if(success) return;

 // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

 // Get the path to the database in the application package
 NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

 // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
 [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];


}
```

to fill an array with a particular column of the table:

import database.h in your ViewController.m and write this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

 [self queryNomi];

}


-(void)queryNomi {

[arrayName removeAllObjects];
[arrayEmail removeAllObjects];

database *dbDelegate = [[database alloc]init];

[dbDelegate startDB];

sqlite3 *database;

NSString *queryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name FROM nameTable"];
NSString *queryEmail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Email FROM nameTable"];


if(sqlite3_open([dbDelegate.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement1;
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement2;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryName UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            [arrayName addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement1, 0)]];

        }

    }

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryEmail UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement2) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            [arrayEmail addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement2, 0)]];
        }

    }


    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement1);
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement2);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}


 //    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I seem to have written it all .. let me know!

Comment: Thank You So Much For the Reply llario....i will try it out Right now

Comment: 1. If you do this, for each of these SQLite calls (especially sqlite3_prepare_v2), you should log sqlite3_errmsg if you didn't get SQLITE_OK. As written, it will be extremely hard to diagnose problems. 2. You should check to see if the string from sqlite3_column_text returned NULL or not, because if it did, stringWithUTF8String will crash. 3. You should probably do this with a single SQL statement. 4. It would be better to have single array of objects (either custom object or dictionary) rather than separate arrays for name and email.

Comment: @Rob This code works,I use it in my app. of course certainly is not the most comfortable solution and it would be better to have a single array of objects. but if the columns are too few and also the values, I do not think it's a problem to have two arrays

Comment: @Ilario Agreed, the OP _could_ do four separate arrays, but really shouldn't. It's both more logical as well as more robust to have an array of `Contact` objects (or `NSDictionary` objects). But, I didn't mean to suggest that your answer wouldn't work, because it will: I just tried to offer some constructive suggestions to make it more robust and efficient.

Comment: @Rob you're absolutely right, even reading your reply I will try to use FMDB, maybe it's better ;)

Comment: FMDB definitely simplifies your life, especially when using `?` placeholders in your SQL.